# Where should i place environment file in a react based client side application?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, environment-variables

In my react application ,i have placed environment file named ".env.local" in src folder.And i have moved the firebaseConfig object to environment file.But i am getting an error which is telling that
api key is not found.So ,what should i do to solve this problem.

Comment: did you prefix it with REACT_APP_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place the ".env.local" file in the root of your application with the package.json file. Don't place the file in other folder.